# Orange texture in blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

How can i recreate this orange procedural texture in blender?
[image]

Comment: This is a photo, it's not procedural, with procedural you can easily reproduce bumps of exterior, but this sliced fruit is a photo, you can also see its copyright watermark if you zoom in.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make this texture in blender except through texture painting.

Comment: perhaps there's a way to do it but do you have a reason to prefer procedural rather than with an image texture?